# Adding a GitHub framework to an XCode Project using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, frameworks

*Sorry if this is too basic, I'm a kind of a rookie on app development.*

I've been trying to add [this GitHub framework](https://github.com/craiggrummitt/SpriteKitEasingSwift) for SpriteKit easing to my XCode project. The only steps for installation (that doesn't require CocoaPods) the framework provides are: *1: Drag the Pod/Classes folder into your project. 2: Import the frameworks in the _Archive folder.*

[image]
However, it doesn't seem to work after doing this. I can't import the framework into my swift files, and I can't use the actions. I may've done the 2nd step wrong, I may not have done it as it's supposed. I've searched all over the internet for ways to import a GitHub framework into XCode, but every answer seems to be different and specific for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed the second step (you say there is 'only step'). The second step is to drag the framework from the _Archive folder. You can find it in the clone of the project folder. Also, try the sample project and see how it's organized. Make sure that you add the framework to the Link Binaries... section in the project Build Phases.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just edited the question. The problem is I don't know how or where to add these frameworks.

Comment: I dropped "SpriteKitEasing.framework" on the navigator, and it was automatically added to the "link binary with libraries". I still can't "import SpriteKitEasing" or use the actions.

Comment: Why not use the sample project in the github download. I ran it here and i works fine. Move your code into a copy of that and you're golden.